# NSM htaccess generator error EE2.8.1

Tags: htaccess

I'm running into what looks like an incompatibility for NSM htaccess generator with ee2.8.1

Trying to save entries will result in the following error:

*Fatal error: Call to undefined function do_hash() in /home/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/nsm_htaccess_generator/ext.nsm_htaccess_generator.php on line 224*

While trying to go into the settings returns the following error:

*Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Javascript::generate_json() in /home/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/nsm_htaccess_generator/ext.nsm_htaccess_generator.php on line 421*

Does anyone know  of a fix?

Comment: did you have latest version??

Comment: Yes, can latest version of everything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

actually I don't use NSM htaccess generator , but I can help you with this problem.

first thing update to the last version , if you have the last version and still have this problem you can solve it as following:

about the first one:do_hash() problem.

replace `do_hash()` function with PHP’s hashing functions like `sh1`

about the second one `generate_json()` :

replace `$this->EE->javascript->generate_json` with `json_encode`

check it and let me know.

Regard's.

Comment: Great can confirm this worked!

Comment: This also worked with updating Wygwam. Thanks Ahmad!